# Deleting Parent and Child objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

ASP.NET MVC 4 / C#
Entity Framework

I am getting the infamous "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" error when deleting a parent object from the database.

I want my program to delete both the parent and it's dependencies (not just null the foreign key on the child). My research has shown some conflicting information and i'm not sure if the problem is how i'm loading the object right before deletion or if its a configuration of the code first database.

To clarify, my question is: how do I enforce a cascade delete successfully?

Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
//Model
public class JobList
{
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

public List<Options> option { get; set; }
    public JobList(){
    option = new List<Options>();
}

public class Options
{
    public JobList joblist { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set;}
}



//Controller
    JobList joblist = db.JobListDB.Find(id);
    db.JobListDB.Remove(joblist);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently writing out your issue can help you to figure out your own problem. I had to set the foreign key as a required item to enforce the cascade delete. For those with a similar issue this is what the code is like now:

```
//Model
public class JobList
{
    public string jobName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<Options> option { get; set; }
    public JobList(){
    option = new List<Options>();
}

public class Options
{
    [Required]
    public JobList joblist { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set;}
}
```